# Checking if the SD card is available

Tags: android, android-external-storage

Am using the following code to check if the SD card is available. But it returns false even if the card is present on my android emulator. I can see that by manually going to settings.

```
public static final boolean isSDCardPresent(){
        Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        Boolean isSDSupportedDevice = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();

        if(isSDSupportedDevice && isSDPresent) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

To give a bigger picture, what am trying to do is download file to some place on phone. I think external storage is correct place.

```
File soundDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), SOUND_DOWNLOAD_DIR);
```

But soudDir doesnot exists when i do `soundDir.exists()`. Why?

Comment: For API 24+ You can use [`StorageManager.getStorageVolumes()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html#getStorageVolumes()) and look for volume that `isRemovable()`.

Comment: Pls see my latests edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the config.ini of your emulator?
Check where you installed your emulator and see if hw.sdCard is set to yes, so:

```
 hw.sdCard=yes
```